# C++'s min_element() not working for array

Tags: c++, arrays, min

I am trying to find the minimal element of a subset of an array in c++ as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::min_element;

void load_values(int n);
unsigned *w;

int main() {
   int n, a, b;
   cin >> n >> a >> b;
   w = new unsigned[n];
   load_values(n); // sets values to w[i]
   int min = min_element(w+a, w+b);
   }

void load_values(int n) {
 while(n--)
    w[n] = 1;
}
```

I get the error `invalid conversion from 'unsigned int*' to 'unsigned int' [-fpermissive]`. What am I missing here?

Comment: You have a memory leak. (that was a hint to maybe not use C arrays because it's C++).

Comment: Also, sans `load_values()` insides, the rest of the code compiles. Show the body of said function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, that `std::min_element()` returns an iterator to a minimal value, not the value itself. I doubt that you get this error based on the above code alone: assuming proper include directives and using directives the code compiles OK although it would print the address of the minimum element rather than its value. Most likely your actual code looks more like

```
unsigned min = std::min_element(w + a, w + b);
```

Note, that you should also check the result of reading from `std::cin`:

```
if (std::cin >> n >> a >> b) {
   // process the values
}
```

... and, of course, it seems you're leaking the memory allocated for `w`.

Comment: This question really needed downvote + vtc, not answers.

Comment: My code really looks like that in fact. Thanks!

Comment: @DeadMG: I appreciate pointing out that the downvote has nothing to do with the quality of the answer but rather with the existence of the answer at all.

Comment: It sucks to be left poring over your answer trying to figure out what's wrong with it. FTR, that's a pretty nice piece of psychic debugging. But it's wasted here on this questioner and you're just encouraging more bad behaviour by providing it, so I felt compelled to express that it was not actually helpful.