# Find min value in array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, iterator, min

I have two arrays:

```
int playerSums[9] = { };
string playerNames[9] = { };
```

I am trying to get the **smallest value** in the array `playerSums` and also the **array index** of this value.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
if (playerNames[index] == "End" || playerNames[index] == "end") {
    int lowestValue = playerSums[0];
    for (i = 1; i < sizeof(playerSums) / sizeof(playerSums[0]); i++) {
        if (playerSums[i] < lowestValue || lowestValue != 0)
            lowestValue = playerSums[i]; 
    }
    cout << index[playerNames] << " had the lowest values and got the sum ";
    cout << lowestValue << endl;
}
```

How do I find and display the smallest value in the array `playerSums` if for example *only 3 players* are playing, i.e. only 3 elements of the array are populated (and the rest of the elements are equal to zero)?

I need the index to display the name of the player who got the smallest value.

Comment: Please explain what your current code does wrong.  While you are at it, explain the logic behind the inner `if` statement :)

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871658/cs-min-element-not-working-for-array?

Comment: `std::vector` makes life so much easier.

Comment: Also, you can use struct to store playerSum and playerName in one array.

Comment: It currently shows a blank name in the last cout line and also the a sum of 0. :(. The if statement, was a copy paste of a tutorial for this but i can't figure it out...

Comment: @FredLarson Or even [`std::array<int,9> playerSums; std::array<std;;string,9> playerNames;`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) seems to be easier to handle.

Comment: You could implement your own comparison function and use this : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min_element/

Comment: @Aif: provided that he'll pack the data into container of structs.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: But I think `std::vector` makes more sense, since he wants to handle a varying number of players (not always 9).

Comment: Hm... what the hell is `index`? It's not equal to index of player which got the lowest score.

Comment: @FredLarson Of course `std::vector` would be the _abstracted_ solution. I just wanted to drop in the c++ equivalents, as of what's shown in the question sample.

Comment: Your code fails for "eNd" or "EnD".  I recommend converting to all uppercase or all lower case before comparing.  This will reduce to one compare.  Search the web for "c++ transform toupper".'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use standard algorithm `std::min_element` declared in header `<algorithm>` that to find the element witn minimum sum. For example

```
#include <algorithm>

int *min = std::min_element( playerSums, playerSums + 3 );

std::cout <<  playerNames[min - playerSums] 
          << " had the lowest values and got the sum " << *min
          << std::endl;
```

The same can be written using standard functions `std::begin`, `std::end` and `std::distance` declared in header `<iterator>`

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int *min = std::min_element( std::begin( playerSums ), std::end( playerSums ) );

std::cout <<  playerNames[ std::distance( playerSums, min )] 
          << " had the lowest values and got the sum " << *min
          << std::endl;
```

Instead of using the algorithm you could write your own function similar to the algorithm. For example

```
size_t min_sum( const int playerSums[], size_t n )
{
   size_t min = 0;

   for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
   {
      if ( playerSums[min] < playerSums[i] ) min = i;
   }

   return min;
}

size_t min = min_sum( playerSums, sizeof( playerSums ) / sizeof( *playerSums )  );

std::cout <<  playerNames[min] 
          << " had the lowest values and got the sum " << playerSums[min]
          << std::endl;
```

If you need to skip elements of the array that equal to zero then the function will look like

```
size_t min_sum( const int playerSums[], size_t n )
{
   size_t min = 0;

   while ( min < n && playerSums[i] == 0 ) ++min;

   for ( size_t i = min; i < n; i++ )
   {
      if ( playerSums[min] < playerSums[i] ) min = i;
   }

   return min;
}

size_t min = min_sum( playerSums, sizeof( playerSums ) / sizeof( *playerSums )  );

if ( min != sizeof( playerSums ) / sizeof( *playerSums ) )
{   
    std::cout <<  playerNames[min] 
              << " had the lowest values and got the sum " << playerSums[min]
              << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As usual the simplest solution is to use the *standard library*, e.g.

```
auto it = std::min_element(std::begin(playerSums), std::end(playerSums));
std::size_t index = std::distance(std::begin(playerSums), it);
```

Now you can get the min value by dereferencing the iterator `it`:

```
int lowestValue = *it;
```

If you only want to iterate over the **first 3** elements in the array then you can do something like this instead:

```
auto first = std::begin(playerSums);
auto it = std::min_element(first, std::next(first, 3));
std::size_t index = std::distance(first, it);
```

*Note:* prefer `std::next` instead of plain pointer arithmetics (e.g. `playerSums + 3`) as it is more generic (works on all iterator types).

Comment: "dereferencing `it`" means writing `*it`.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus Yes, use the *dereference operator* `*`.

Comment: The way I read the question, the arrays are allocated for up to 9 players, but there may be fewer players than that playing the game. Assuming the unused array entries are filled with zeroes, how does one find the minimum ignoring the unused entries?

Comment: This answer solved my issue. when using +size it would say the operator + is not defined.

Answer (score 4):

The same way that you are storing the lowest value in `lowestValue`, store the index in a variable, let's say, `lowestValueIndex`. Also, remove the outer if and move it inside the for loop:

```
if(playerNames[i] == "End" || playerNames[i] == "end")
    break;
```

this way, you will make sure that only the players who are playing will be processed. Also, you won't need to check if the lowest value is zero anymore. So the code will look like:

```
int lowestValue = playerSums[0];
int lowestValueIndex = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < sizeof(playerSums)/sizeof(playerSums[0]); ++i)
{
    if(playerNames[i] == "End" || playerNames[i] == "end")
        break;
    if (playerSums[i] < lowestValue)
    {
            lowestValue = playerSums[i];
            lowestValueIndex = i;
    }
}
cout << index[playerNames] << " had the lowest values and got the sum "
     << lowestValue << endl;
```

Just as a note, use an standard array that can grow to simplify this (like a `vector`):

```
std::vector<std::string> playerNames;
std::vector<int> playerSums;

for (int i = 1; i < playerSums.size(); ++i)
{
    if (playerSums[i] < lowestValue)
    {
            lowestValue = playerSums[i];
            lowestValueIndex = i;
    }
}
cout << index[playerNames] << " had the lowest values and got the sum "
     << lowestValue << endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

First adjust your for loop condition. I'm not sure if you defined i before so maybe you forgot that. Second the stop condition i < sizeof(palyerSums) is sufficient. Also you only need to store the index of the lowest playerSums in the array. The if condition also has something too much. If the lowestValue is not zero you will always change that value, that doesn't seem right unless the lowestValue is exactly zero.

```
int lowestValue = playerSums[0];
int resultIndex = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < sizeof(playerSums) / sizeof(playerSums[0]); i++) {
  if(playerSums[i] < lowestValue) {
    lowestValue = playerSums[i];
    resultIndex = i;
  }
}
cout << playerNames[resultIndex] << "blabla" << lowestValue; // instead of lowestValue you could also do playerSums[resultIndex] ofcourse.
```

Let me know if that works

Comment: Size of array != Length of array

Comment: My bad I'm not familiar with c++ but that makes sense then with the division.

Answer (score 2):

You know the index of the element you assign to `lowestValue` when you change that variable's value, so just save that index in a variable (say, `index`), so that when you are done `index` has the index of the last value assigned.