# Find minimum value of member in list<MyStruct> using STL

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stl-algorithm

I have list of MyStruct objects.

```
struct Task {
    std::function<void()> _fn = nullptr;
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point _execTime;
};
```

How to find minimum value of _execTime in list using STL algorithm ? I can find with iteration, but is there more elegant way to do this? 
Something like below:

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point nearestExecTime = std::min(auto t = tasks.begin(), auto p = tasks.end(), [t,p]() {return t.execTime < p.exeTime;});
```

Comment: I think you want [`std::min_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find min value in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26166337/find-min-value-in-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::min_element`.

```
std::min_element(tasks.begin(), tasks.end(),
[](const Task& t, const Task& p) { return t._execTime < p._execTime; });
```

Comment: It doesn't work.
_"No member named '_execTime' in 'std::chrono::time_point<...>...'"_

Comment: I think it should be:
`std::min_element(tasks.begin(), tasks.end(), [](const Task& t, const Task&p) { return t._execTime < p._execTime; });`